# ASP.NET Core SignInmanager source

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Where can I find source code for **microsoft.aspnetcore.identity**.signinmanager ?
I am mostly coming accross source code for **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin**.signinmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the source code here.

[public class SignInManager where TUser : class](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/84c0baa9a57bd6448cd1bf78b64d2c1658bf5ef6/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L1)

Comment: I wonder how you managed to come upon it. I couldn't locate it for my life. Thanks a bunch!